# Can I add pipe to binding @input decoprador property?

Tags: angular

I've a component with a @Input property:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-details',
  templateUrl: './product-details.component.html'
})
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product: Product;
}
```

I'd like to binding this property like this:

```html
<app-products-by-category [products]="products | filterByCategory('pizza')"></app-products-by-category>
```

that causes the following error:

```sh
ERROR in Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '(' at column 28 in [products | filterByCategory('pizza')] in D:/private projects/ecommerces/fuzionm-store/frontend/src/app/modules/product/components/products/products.component.html@3:42 (" class="container" *ngIf="products$ | async as products">
    <app-products-by-category [products]="[ERROR ->]products | filterByCategory('pizza')" [category]=categories.PIZZA></app-products-by-category>
    <!-"): D:/private projects/ecommerces/fuzionm-store/frontend/src/app/modules/product/components/products/products.component.html@3:42
Parser Error: Unexpected token '(' at column 28 in [products | filterByCategory('pizza')] in product/components/products/products.component.html@3:42 ("oducts">
    <app-products-by-category [products]="products | filterByCategory('pizza')" [category]=[ERROR ->]categories.PIZZA></app-products-by-category>
    <!-- <app-products-by-category [products]="filterByC"): product/components/products/products.component.html@3:91
```

Is there possible to add a pipe in this scenario?

Comment: You cannot use parentheses with pipes. You need to use `:` Try `[products]="products | filterByCategory: 'pizza' "` See: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#transforming-data-with-parameters-and-chained-pipes

Comment: What happens when you write it like `[products]="products | filterByCategory:'pizza'"`?

Comment: The better way is to use the pipe in your component